# Finding out which module is setting the root logger

Tags: python, logging

How would I be able to find which module is overriding the Python root logger?

My Django project imports from quite a few external packages, and I have tried searching for all instances of logging.basicConfig and logging.root setups, however most of them are in tests and should not be overriding it unless specifically called.

Django's logging config does not specify a root logger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the solution was to do some monkey patching of the Python logging module.
I just wrapped a decorator around the logging.root.addHandler function that printed the stack and voila, I found my culprit who was calling logging.getLogger(). If you call getLogger without any parameters, you get the root logger.

```
import logging
import sys
import traceback
def tracer(func):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            traceback.print_stack(sys.stderr)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(sys.stderr)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_func
old_addHandler = logging.root.addHandler
logging.root.addHandler = tracer(old_addHandler)

# run your code
```

Comment: Note that this code needs to be inserted above your imports so that it will print when they try to set the root logger. Also, position of args has changed: both the sys.stderr references need to be `file=sys.stderr`.

Comment: By the way, `logging.basicConfig` now has a `force=True` argument, so you don't necessarily have to find out who is setting the root logger to override it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean `import logging` imports a different logging module?  In this case, there are many special attributes of modules/packages that can help, such as `__path__`.  Printing `logging.__path__` should tell you where python is importing it from.

Comment: I'm afraid not, I'm referring to the standard logging module.